# Which 6-bit string would represent an optimal solution for trap-3 in the Linkage Learning Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms

I am struggling to learn certain Evolutionary algorithm concepts and also relations between each of them. I am going through the Linkage Learning Genetic Algorithm (LLGA) right now and came across this question:

*Which 6-bit string of LLGA would represent an optimal solution for trap-3?*

Can anyone give me an answer or explain it?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Can you quote it? Because I cannot really understand this "what 6-bit string of LLGA that would represent an optimal solution for Trap-3". Also, please, put your question in the title.

Comment: I have edited your post to clarify what I think is your question. Please, make sure that this is the case. It would also be useful if you can tell us which resource you are using to learn about LLGA and what are your definitions of "trap-3".

Comment: Thank you for the edit @nbro. I am searching and reading research papers about these topics. I don't have a specific resource that I am following.

Comment: Which research papers are you reading on these topics? Context can be very useful to help the potential answerers to help you more and more specifically. So, it may be worth citing them (or provide a link to them), and maybe quote relevant parts of those papers that caused you to ask this question. So, I suggest that you edit your post to do this.